# Accessing Elements from Other Processes

Tags: c#, interprocess

I would like to “read” information from a window not related to my program.
If I have a process ID and a window handle:

```
Process Proc = Process.GetProcessById(ProcID);
IntPtr hdl = Proc.MainWindowHandle;
```

And I have information from spy++ telling me that the control-ID of the element I’m interested in is 00000003EA, how can I access it with C#?

Thanks for your help!

Edit_____________________________________

In case anyone is interested, this is how I got it working:

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(ProcID);
IntPtr hdl = p.MainWindowHandle;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //Assume that 1024 bytes are enough! Better would be to get the text length..
UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
uint Test = GetDlgItemText((int)hdl, Convert.ToInt32("0x000003EA", 16), buffer, 1024);
string TextFromOtherWindow = enc.GetString(buffer);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetDlgItemText(
 int hDlg,           //A handle to the dialog box that contains the control. 
 int nIDDlgItem,     //The identifier of the control whose title or text is to be retrieved. 
 byte[] lpString,      //The buffer to receive the title or text. 
 int nMaxCount       //The maximum length, in characters, of the string to be copied to the 
 //buffer pointed to by lpString. If the length of the string, including 
 //the null character, exceeds the limit, the string is truncated. 
);
```

`byte[] buffer` is the buffer where the text from the other window is written back to.  I assumed that the text is no more than 1024 bytes long, but it would be better to get the actual size…

As far as the encoding goes, a different one might be better suited for your needs.

The Handle in Hex needs to be converted to an integer: `Convert.ToInt32("0x000003EA", 16)`

**GetDlgItemText** was best suited (I think) for my requirement of getting the static text as opposed to “**SendMessage**” and “**WM_GETTEXT**”.

Thanks to all who helped point me in the right direction!

Source for GetDlgItemText: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Edit_________________________________

Hmmm. I spoke too soon... The element ID is changed each time the program is started.  I have opened a new question at [Persistent Element Identification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161970/persistent-element-identification).

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352236/reading-from-a-text-field-in-another-applications-window

Comment: Can I ask what process ? is it a .net Process ?

Comment: That link is for C++, which could do the trick, but I have no idea what it means :-(   It is the Installer from AutoCAD that I'm trying to wrap.

Comment: [SendMessage function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) and [how to use Sendmessage in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/94e500c8-6d1b-43bf-9c04-9823597525bf)

Comment: @Daro: The problem is it's not possible to do in "pure C#", you'll have to use pinvoke (see pinvoke.net) to call some C++ code.

Comment: So I need do do something like this?  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(
int hWnd, // handle to destination window
uint Msg, // message
long wParam, // first message parameter
long lParam // second message parameter
);
What Message do I need to send, and how do I access the specific element?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going with the [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Though that's not perfect as many applications do not support that.

Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503027/pinvoke-setfocus-to-a-particular-control/9547099#9547099) of mine, similar question, might help with being able to access / 'attach' to other process threads / queues etc.

EDIT: (I forgot to link up on my other post, just corrected:)

Answer (score 0):

WCF, Webservices are there to make inter-process communication easy.

Comment: So how would the webservice read the text of the control? The OP  stated that he doesn't have control over the source of the other process

Comment: No. I have no control over the other program.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into something like this 
[Managed Spy ++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx)

This might also help [Find Window in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508514/create-the-function-find-window-of-spy-in-c-sharp)