# How to list all the elements of an application?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to click a button on a windows application from other application. Basically, I want to click app B's button from app A's code.

I can use winapi findWindow to get a handler. The problem is that I have no idea the name of the button on the app B. Is this possible to list all the names or ids of an application?

I'm using c# to make it happen.

Comment: @Arion // None so far. I tried to google, got nothing. I know that this question might not fit here since I don't have any source code, but...I have no idea how to approach this problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looking at suggestions (it's a pretty generic question really, it might or might not work depending on what other app/window is, is it e.g. browser or a 3rd party app etc., does it support automation)

Take a look at this closely related answer (it might be a duplicate but you're kind of 'looking for' still so maybe note).

[Accessing Elements from Other Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129017/accessing-elements-from-other-processes/10129640#10129640)

Also this one on how to 'access' other app's 'inputs'
[Pinvoke SetFocus to a particular control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503027/pinvoke-setfocus-to-a-particular-control/9547099#9547099)

Comment: NSGaga // Thank you for the post!

Comment: @Moon np - Your best bet is going with the [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). or accessibility (older version of it sort of), still nothing is guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested this. But it looks like a intressting libary. Maybe there is some function you can use. It is called [White](http://white.codeplex.com/). This is just a sample:

```
Application application = Application.Launch("foo.exe");
Window window = application.GetWindow("bar", InitializeOption.NoCache);

Button button = window.Get<Button>("save");
button.Click();
```

Comment: sure does, though should be given some testing

Answer (score 1):

You can use tool such as Spy++ (included in any Visual Studio except Express editions) to find name and class of that button and then use these information as parameters of FindWindow().

Comment: great! Spy++ seems very useful